# Possibly corrupt USB stick not recognized

Tags: 16.04, usb

I'm having a problem with a USB stick I use for university (it includes important files for me). Unfortunately my laptop does not recognize it.

I have tried `lsblk` but it doesn't even show up, neither in disks utility nor in gparted.

The only thing I imagine might be handy are the last lines from `dmesg`.

[image: dmesg log]

Note that:

- I have no other USB drives connected
- This USB stick does not work on university's computers

Comment: You can try according to the following link and links from it. But don't try to format or restore it, if there are valuable files. [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: Well, after applying all the commands from paragraph 3 (when drive cannot be found) i had no luck! Can't seem to detect it, so the last resort would be mkusb, which from what I understood you wouldn't advice if I don't want to loose my files.

Comment: That is right, but on the other hand, if the system does not detect the drive and `lsblk` does not show it, `mkusb` will not reach it (it depends on `lsblk`). The alternative to clone the drive with `ddrescue` will probably fail too in your case. See [this link for more details](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986). Scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files'. I am sorry, but I think that your drive, the USB stick, is damaged beyond repair.